# Converting incorrect timezone

Tags: r, datetime, timezone

I have a POSIXct variable that reads 2016-12-15 20:11:29 PST  but the PST is incorrect. It should actually read 2016-12-15 20:11:29 GMT

I need to make the time zone correct, GMT, then I need to convert it to New York time

So I am given 2016-12-15 20:11:29 PST.  It really should be 2016-12-15 20:11:29 GMT then I need to convert 2016-12-15 20:11:29 GMT to "America/New_York"  so the final result will be 16:11:29 America/New_York because new york time is BEHIND GMT time.

I've tried this many ways but can't get it to work. Any ideas?

```
 p = as.POSIXct("2016-12-15 20:11:29 PST")
 p
```

********** UPDATE *********
my real code uses a variable and the suggested solutions do not work. see below

```
     p = as.POSIXct("2016-12-15 20:11:29 PST")
          out = as.POSIXct(p, tz="GMT")
          out
          attr(out,"tzone") <- "America/New_York"
          out

>           out
[1] "2016-12-15 20:11:29 PST"
>           attr(out,"tzone") <- "America/New_York"
>           out
[1] "2016-12-15 23:11:29 EST"  ### this is incorrect
```

*** This also doe snot work

```
 p = as.POSIXct(p, usetz=TRUE, tz="GMT")
      (format(p, tz="America/New_York") )

[1] "2016-12-15 23:11:29 EST"
> p = as.POSIXct(p, usetz=TRUE, tz="GMT")
>           (format(p, tz="America/New_York") )
[1] "2016-12-15 23:11:29"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your `p` is in your system timezone by default:

```
p = as.POSIXct("2016-12-15 20:11:29 PST")
p
# I'm in Australian Eastern Standard Time, AEST
#[1] "2016-12-15 20:11:29 AEST"
as.numeric(p)
#[1] 1481796689
```

Convert this local datetime to `UTC`, which changes the underlying data, by formatting and resetting the timezone to GMT (unless you are already in GMT, then it will do nothing of course):

```
p2 <- as.POSIXct(format(p),tz="UTC")
p2
#[1] "2016-12-15 20:11:29 UTC"
as.numeric(p2)
#[1] 1481832689
p2 - p
#Time difference of 10 hours
# ...which is the difference between AEST and GMT
```

Then you can adjust the timezone attribute, which will just alter the display of the date/time object. It does not affect the underlying numeric data:

```
attr(p2,"tzone") <- "America/New_York"
p2
#[1] "2016-12-15 15:11:29 EST"

as.numeric(p2)
#[1] 1481832689
```

Answer (score 2):

I can get you most of the way there but R thinks your are wrong about the time differential:

```
> p = as.POSIXct("2016-12-15 20:11:29 PST", usetz=TRUE, tz="GMT")
>  p
[1] "2016-12-15 20:11:29 GMT"
> (format(p, tz="America/New_York") )
[1] "2016-12-15 15:11:29"
```

---

Response to edit. I'm not seeing the problem. The numeric representation of time in R is always GMT. You can do things at input with parameter to blank out the wrong tz but then your output with `format` or `strftime` will simply need to specify a parameter for a different timezone. ( using a variable should have no effect.)

```
 p = "2016-12-15 20:11:29 PST"
 pp = as.POSIXct(p, usetz=TRUE, tz="GMT")
 pp
[1] "2016-12-15 20:11:29 GMT"
```

Comment: `out <- as.POSIXct("2016-12-15 20:11:29 PST", tz="GMT"); attr(out,"tzone") <- "America/New_York"` if you want to keep the POSIXct structure but change the timezone. But I agree that the result is 15:11:29

Comment: I see that this works in your code but in my real code i hav a varaible, var, instead of the string date. so it looks something like  as.POSIXct(var, usetz=TRUE, tz="GMT") and it does not work.  I will try to reproduce and update the question